# Trying to build a DELETE URL from List, getting 'Illegal character in URL' error

Tags: httprequest

[image: URL as captured in log entry. First line break is likely due to field length; after contactIds=, the line breaks appear to be newlines inserted as part of URL assembly]<< I've added this image, captured as System Log entry.  Line breaks after 'contactIds=' appear to be the result of the assembly process.

The request I'm trying to assemble consists of an endpoint appended with a list of comma-separated values/Ids.  When I manually tested the process using a single value, not a problem.  I'm getting a list of records, extracting the ids, and then passing those along to my DELETE method.

Whether I build the string as part of the extraction, inserting commas, and passing that along, or collecting them in an array and assembling the string later, I continue to run into the problem.

```
    String endPt = CampaignJSONUtils.getContactListUpdateURL(contactListId) + '?contactIds=';
    for(String s : contactData){
        endPt += contactData + ',';
    }
    endPt = endPt.left(endPt.length()-1);
    req.setEndpoint(endPt);
```

CampaignJSONUtils is used in other places w/o issue, so it's somewhere between adding '?contactIds=' and assembling the csv list where it hits.

I have a cleanStr() method that I could rework to leave in commas; perhaps I need to run my finished URL (or the end thereof) through it -- I'll try that in the morning unless someone has a better plan in the meantime.

Comment: What does the URL look like if you `System.debug()` it? Are you sure the values in `contactData` are valid Salesforce Ids?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but something worthy of note. You can replace your for loop and string manipulation with `String.join()` a la `endPt += String.join(contactData, ',');`

Comment: The Ids are definitely not valid Salesforce Ids, but then, I'm not using them in a Salesforce instance.  I'll give String.join() a chance, thanks!  (I'm usually a splitter, not a joiner...)

Comment: Sadly, not the issue: still seeing the error with Cause: null from System.CalloutException.

Comment: The URL is getting truncated in this comment :( https://api.myexternalprovider.com/api/v2/outbound/contactlists/e287404b-e731-4168-99fe-af1c152037fd/contacts?contactIds=
899ed5e843f5405064e9114c67b6780b,
1b76bc708c606190cbcdfa1f20b55f7, which clearly appears to have newlines before each entry.  If I modify the process to select just the first Id and ignore the rest, then it results in:https://api.myexternalprovider.com/api/v2/outbound/contactlists/e287404b-e731-4168-99fe-af1c152037fd/contacts?contactIds=899ed5e843f5405064e9114c67b6780b, which doesn't have that newline issue. Adding commas...

Comment: (cont.) appears to be the cause, though inserting a comma immediately after ?contactIds doesn't cause the same error.